# Populate Kendo grid with Ajax result

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to be able to use the result of the ajax call to make a decision which Kendo Grid I will populate.  If I receive only one item in the array I want to populate a grid, otherwise I have another grid for multiple items.

**My jQuery**

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'Item/GetItems/',
        data: { number: number },
        success: function (data) {

            if (data.length == 1) {
                var sGrid = $("#SingleGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data(data);

                //I´ve also tried this
                //sGrid.refresh();
            }
            else {
                var mGrid = $("#MultipleGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data(data);

                //I´ve also tried this
                //mGrid .refresh();
            }
        },
        error: function () {
        }
    });
```

**My Controller Action**

```
    public ActionResult GetItems([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string number)
    {
        var items = _idg.GetItems(number);
        return Json(items.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }
```

I´ve been monitoring Firebug and it shows no errors.  I´m trying to prevent the second call to the server by making the decision to populate one of the grids.  Is there a way force dataSource refresh like this client-side?  (without calling the read function on the dataSource which would call the server the second time)

**###### EDITED ########**

```
function TestGrid() {
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: 'Item/GetItems/'
            }
        },
        schema: {
            data: function (response) {
                // Here the Total is always correct
                return response.Total;
            }
        }
    });

    dataSource.fetch(function () {
        var kendoGrid;
        var data = this.data();
        //Here the data does not include my Total
        alert(data);
        if (data.length == 1) {
            kendoGrid = $("#SingleGrid").data("kendoGrid");
        } else {
            kendoGrid = $("#MultipleGrid").data("kendoGrid");
        }
        kendoGrid.setDataSource(dataSource);
        kendoGrid.refresh();
    });
}
```

From my example above I can´t seem to reach the total number from this.data().  When I debug with Firebug I can see that the Total number is always correct.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could populate a new instance of a kendo datasource, load the data, then acting on the results, set the datasource of the grid. Maybe something like this:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  transport: {
    read:  {
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: 'Item/GetItems/',
      data: { number: number },
    }
  }
});
```

Then fetch the data from the server and act on the result:

```
dataSource.fetch(function() {
  var data = this.data();
  var kendoGrid;
  if (data.length == 1) {
    kendoGrid = $("#SingleGrid").data("kendoGrid");
  } else {
    kendoGrid = $("#MultipleGrid").data("kendoGrid");
  }
  // Replace the grids data source with our new populated data source
  kendoGrid.setDataSource(dataSource);
  kendoGrid.refresh();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @boniestlawyer, I implemented as you suggested but my grids are still not showing the data. I can see in Firebug that the data is being passed from the controller but not appearing.  When I count the elements in the new dataSource (with the total() function) I always receive none as if the dataSource is empty.  Perhaps I´m using a wrong function to count the dataSource or perhaps I´m populating the dataSource not in the correct way.  Any ideas?  :)

Comment: I suspect it would be something to do with the data coming down to the browser. Try adding a schema->data function to your kendo datasource like this: http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-schema , and debug the function to inspect the response that you are getting.

Comment: It´s probably like you´re suggesting, that the data from the server is somehow not coming correctly through, or at least not being correctly databound.  Am I correct to assume that the dataSource always reads data from the controller as DataSourceResult? (like my example shows)

Comment: It appears to be correct. The javascript side of the kendo datasource doesn't necessarily have to bind to a DataSourceResult, it go read from pretty much any JSON data, it just helps massage the data so you don't need to do as much plumbing on the client side.

Comment: Hello again @boniestlawyer. Now I´m back at this issue.  How would you count the elements in the datasource?  What would you use to return the length of the datasource as in your example above?

Comment: If you are referring to "if (data.length == 1) {" there should be a assigning of a data variable that gets the data from the datasource - i've updated the example above with that

Comment: I used the schema as stated in the documentation but for some reason I can´t reach the total number.  I´ve edited my question if you would be so kind to assist me further :)

Comment: You're asking multiple questions in one and making it all confusing - I would break these up into different questions. Does my original answer resolve your original question? With regards to your edit - your schema.data function is returning what I assume is a number, and according to kendo documentation here http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-schema.data it expects an array.

Comment: Sorry for the multiple questions, your code is of course right, I was just wondering further with the schema and data being passed on.  Thank you for your help  :)

Comment: Anyway, I got this to work by changing "Total" to "Data" in the schema part of the datasource declaration.  Thanx again @boniestlawyer.

Comment: ah okay, so I guess that was the format of your JSON. Glad to be of help

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this things.

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "http://localhost:13073/home/KendoGriddata",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "Post",
                        data: function () {
                            var dt = { MultipleSearchText: 'rikin' };
                            return dt;
                        }
                    }
                },
                pageSize: 5    
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try such a variant:

```
var grid = $('#SingleGrid').getKendoGrid(); 
grid.dataSource.data(data);
grid.refresh();
```